# When rebuilding tensorflow for android I'm getting a fatal error: 'stdlib.h' file not found

Tags: android, tensorflow, python-3.5

In Ubuntu 16.04, when running an Android Tensorflow TFDetect implementation using my protobuf file, I received an error stating **"No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'ceil'"**. I had to modify the mobile build to include the proper .cc files and I then proceeded to run the following command to build the jar after rebuilding Tensorflow:

> bazel build -c opt
>   //tensorflow/contrib/android:libtensorflow_inference.so
>   --crosstool_top=//external:android/crosstool    --host_crosstool_top=@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain    --cpu=armeabi-v7a

I then receive the error stating that the build was not complete due to stdlib.h missing:

> In file included from
>   external/androidndk/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/algorithm:62:
>   In file included from
>   external/androidndk/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/bits/stl_algo.h:59:
>   external/androidndk/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include/cstdlib:72:10:
>   fatal error: 'stdlib.h' file not found

I see many others being told to use the prebuilt binaries, but this will not work for me as I need some additional kernels that are stripped for mobile.

Anyone have any ideas as to how I can build the necessary android jar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found the issue. At the following link below it states that bazel is not supported by NDK version 16. I had originally installed 14b, but at one point when I opened my project in Android Studio, it asked to update the NDK and I upgraded. When I happened to be troubleshooting this issue I noticed that it was version 16 and then ended up removing that and installing version 14. After rebuilding all source and then performing the above call to bazel, everything went through smoothly. Stupid mistake on my part.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/android/README.md